# C++ Array structure

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have made a book storage program in c++. It is program which loops over 3 times so the user can input 3 books but now I want user to pick the amount of book user wants to enter and I have no clue how to do it. It would be helpful and here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Book{
    string name;
    int release;
}Issue[3];

int main(){
    //local variable
    int i;
    string release_dte;
    //interface
    cout << "Welcome to Book Storage CPP" << endl;
    //for handler
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Book: ";
        getline(cin, Issue[i].name);
        cout << "Release Date: ";
        getline(cin, release_dte);
        Issue[i].release = atoi(release_dte.c);
    }
    cout << "These are your books" << endl;
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Book: " << Issue[i].name << " Release Date: " << Issue[i].release << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use std::vector. For example

```
#include <vector>
//...

struct Book{
    string name;
    int release;
};

int main()
{
   size_t issue_number;

   std::cout << "Enter number of books: ";
   std::cin >> issue_number;

   std::vector<Book> Issue( issue_number );
//...
```

Otherwise you should dynamically allocate the array yourself. For example

```
Book *Issue = new Book[issue_number];
```

and in the end of the program you need to release the allocated memory

```
delete []Issue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending (and critiquing) Vlad's answer, you won't need the amount of the books beforehand if you utilize stream iterators. You can also overload the stream extractor for `Book` so that the extraction is correctly implemented by the iterators:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Book & b)
{
    if (!is.good())
        return is;

    std::string release_date;

    if (std::getline(is >> std::ws, b.name) &&
        std::getline(is >> std::ws, release_date))
    {
        b.release = std::stoi(release_date);
    }

    return is;
}
```

And later in `main()` you would still use `std::vector<Book>`, only using the iterator overload of the constructor to generate the objects:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Book> Items(std::istream_iterator<Book>{std::cin},
                            std::istream_iterator<Book>{});

    ...
}
```

For printing you can overload the inserter which implements the logic for printing:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Book & b)
{
    return os << "Book: "          << b.name << '\n'
              << " Release Date: " << b.release;
}
```

And invoking this inserter using `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(Items.begin(), Items.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<Book>(std::cout << "These are your books: \n", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>

   using namespace std;

   struct Book {
          string name;
          int release;
          Book(string _name, int _release) {
                 name = _name;
                 release = _release;
          }
   };

   int main() {
          vector<Book> books;
          string name;
          int release;

          while(cin >> name >> release) {
                 books.push_back(Book(name,release));
          }

          for(int i=0; i<(int)books.size(); ++i) {
                 cout << books[i].name << " - " << books[i].release << endl;
          }

          return 0;

   }
```

Comment: This code won't work for the OP's purposes as it requires that `release` be an integer, not a string. Also, the name might take the last name as well which the `>>` operator won't be able to extract. Your  example has a lot of room for improvement.